# why custom delimiters {{{}}} dont work in vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, delimiter

im just trying to use delimiters like {{{ content }}}

added

`delimiters: ['{{{', '}}}']`

to the Vue instance, but still have an error while running `npm run build`

```
- invalid expression: Unexpected token ) in

"\n        "+_s({content)+"}\n      "

Raw expression: {{{content}}}
```

My vuejs version is 1.1.40

What Im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters):

> **Restrictions:** This option is only available in the full build, with in-browser compilation.

If the template is being pre-compiled, you need to use `{{ }}`.